# How to check response body value?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Hi i want to check json response id with user login id stored in share preference
here is my json response

```
{"code":1,"message":"Success","result":[{"id":"1","name":"Albert Einstein","description":"Albert Einstein was a German-born theoretical physicist.","galaxy":"Cartwheel","star":"0008","dob":"1905-05-13","died":"1973-04-06"}]}
```

And here is where i check response body empty or not

```
 retrievedData.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseModel> call, Response<ResponseModel>
                    response) {
                if(response == null || response.body() == null){
                    showInfoDialog(ScientistsActivity.this,"ERROR","Response or Response Body is null. \n Recheck Your PHP code.");
                    return;
                }
                if(response == null || response.body() == null){
                    showInfoDialog(ScientistsActivity.this,"ERROR","Response or Response Body is null. \n Recheck Your PHP code.");
                    return;
                }
                List<Scientist> currentPageScientists = response.body().getResult();

                if (currentPageScientists != null && currentPageScientists.size() > 0) {
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("GET_PAGINATED_SEARCH")) {
                        allPagesScientists.clear();
                    }
                    allPagesScientists.addAll(currentPageScientists);
                    // show(ScientistsActivity.this,currentPageScientists.size()+" Scientists Found");
                } else {
                    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("GET_PAGINATED_SEARCH")) {
                        allPagesScientists.clear();
                    }
                    show(ScientistsActivity.this,"Hey! Reached End. No more Found");
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hideProgressBar(mProgressBar);
            }
```

I dont have any idea about how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use Interceptor with spring boot. You can check all response with postHandle method.

You can visit this page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm